# Seeding model is not working with validatating user in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

My seeds look like:

seeds.rb

```
seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seed.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
Article.create(config["articles"])
User::HABTM_Articles.create(config["articles_users"])
```

seed.yml

```
articles:
  - status: 0
    title: First article
    body: Some awesome text

articles_users:
  - article_id: 1
    user_id: 1
```

I make `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`.

Then  run `rake db:seed --trace` and get output:

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

My `Article` table is empty, but `Article::HABTM_Users` is seeded.

I discovered that problem is in `Article` model:

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :users, presence: true #OK when remove this line
  enum status: [:publ, :priv]
end
```

When remove `validates :users, presence: true` seeding works fine.
How to make seeding run with that user presence validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, at the time you're creating the Article, it has no Users. I know your seed file lists the Users as the *very next thing*, but ActiveRecord isn't patient about validations! So what you need to do is create the ArticleUsers at the exact same time you create the Article, which you can do in a few ways:

- Push the `article_users` definition up and into your `articles` definition:

  ```
  articles:
    - status: 0
      title: First article
      body: Some awesome text
      user_ids: [ 1 ]
  ```

  I did some testing, and this should actually work:

  ```
  irb(main):006:0> Thing.create(name: "thing1", user_ids: [ 1 ] ).users
    User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "thing1"], ["created_at", "2015-07-25 16:38:47.717614"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-25 16:38:47.717614"]]
    SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "things_users" ("user_id", "thing_id") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["thing_id", 2]]
  => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1, name: "Bob", age: nil, created_at: "2015-07-25 16:37:13", updated_at: "2015-07-25 16:37:13">]>
  ```
- Use [factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), which allow you to express a way to generate test objects more elegantly, a more robust [fixture solution](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html), or just turn your seeds file into a Ruby script that knows how to build the seeds properly.

Comment: thanx! setting ````user_ids```` works. + for factories, will investigate